# OpenCv mean returns 4 element tuple

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of contours defined and filled in OpenCV, and I'm trying to use this as a mask to find the mean intensity in each ROI.  I thought I could do this using the `cv2.mean` function with a defined mask.  My code is (`im2` is an image read from file):

```
msk = np.zeros(im2.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.bilateralFilter(im2, 5, 200, 5)
im2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im2,(5,5),0
binImg = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im2, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 55, -5)
contours, heir = cv2.findContours(binImg, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(msk, contours, -1, 255, -1)
print len(contours)
print cv2.mean(im2, mask = msk)
```

This returns:

```
3361
(155.88012076286788, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I thought that I would get a mean intensity per contour, but it looks like an overall mean intensity for each channel (the image is greyscale).  Are my expectations incorrect, or is my code incorrect?

Comment: so, you've drawn all 3361 contours (filled) into a black image, and the mean grayscale value of that image is 156. "I thought that I would get a mean intensity per contour" - clear expectation mismatch.

Comment: what did you *want* to do ? what would a "mean intensity per contour" even signify ?

Comment: Not quite.  I've drawn all 3361 contours (filled) onto a black image, and used THAT image as a mask over a greyscale image to calculate a mean.  I'm not calculating the mean of the mask.

Comment: @berak, I think you're misunderstanding my question.  I'd like to use the mask image to define a set of ROIs, and calculate the mean intensity of the original greyscale image (`im2`) at each ROI.

Comment: yes, i partly misunderstood you. still, you 'd have to calculate things per roi (per contour?), not on the whole image.

Comment: That's exactly what it looks like I have to do.  I thought that applying the mask would just do that, and return a list of intensities.  Clearly, that's NOT the case.  I don't know of a good, compact way of doing this, other than simply using the ROI as a reference, or doing some sort of image multiplication.

Comment: you'll probably have to iterate over the contours found.

Comment: I think you're right.  I was hoping to avoid that, since the code is a bit messy...

Comment: What is the meaning of using a zeros mask? I have seen in other places in opencv but I do not understand.

Comment: It's been a while, but IIRC, it's filling a mask with zeros (black) to apply over a portion of an image.  This effectively removes the zero-masked portion of the image, and allows you to measure the image portions you DO want.

Comment: Fourth element is likely an opaque alpha channel added for 3 channel data without an alpha. Used for completeness when the image does have an alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on this (and close it out), I did resolve it by iterating over contours, and using the contours as a mask for the original image.  The code is:

```
msk = np.zeros(im2.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.bilateralFilter(im2, 5, 200, 5)
im2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im2,(5,5),0)
binImg = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im2, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 55, -5)
contours, heir = cv2.findContours(binImg, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(msk, contours, -1, 255, -1)
for cnt in contours:
    res = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
    (x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
    ctr = (int(x), int(y))
    rad = int(radius)
    circ = cv2.circle(res, ctr, rad,1,-1)
    print "Area: " + str(cv2.contourArea(cnt)), "Mean: " + str(float(cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask=res)[0]))
```

It should be noted that I'm using the `meanStdDev` (I did some editing and wanted to return Std Dev as well), rather than `mean`, but either should work for finding means.  It's still not clear why `mean` seemed to return 4 results (for 4 channels?) on a greyscale image in the original example.

Comment: So this does not give an answer to why cv2.mean returns a tuple, as the question implies. Does anyone know the real answer?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461) :

> The function cv::mean calculates the mean value M of array elements,
> independently for each channel.

It seems that regardless of the number of channels in the input image, `cv2.mean` returns a 4-value tuple, where irrelevant values (such as the last 3 in your example of a grayscale image) are set to zero.

Comment: Yep, the result in C++ is `Scalar`, which is derived from a 4-element `Vec` of doubles, and is mapped to Python as such. This will apply to any situation where a `Scalar` is encountered.